# How to use GoogleAPIClient (deprecated) with SMSRetriver API in Android

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-client, google-signin, sms-retriever-api

I am trying to implement SMS Retriever API for SMS verification. The official way mentioned in the documentation says to use `GoogleApiClient` along with `HintRequest` to retrieve the mobile number from the device

```
HintRequest hintRequest = new HintRequest.Builder()
            .setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)
            .build();

PendingIntent intent = Auth.CredentialsApi.getHintPickerIntent(
            googleApiClient, hintRequest);
try {
    startIntentSenderForResult(intent.getIntentSender(),
                RESOLVE_HINT, null, 0, 0, 0);
} catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But the [`GoogleAPIClient` is deprecated and replaced by `GoogleApi` interface](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/moving-past-googleapiclient_21.html), such as `GoogleSignInClient`. I tried to use `GoogleSignInClient` but `getHintPickerIntent` does not accept it. Is it safe to use the old API even after being deprecated or is there a way to use the latter with SMSRetriver API?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To remove the deprecated `GoogleApiClient`, replace your intent with the following:

```
// Kotlin
val intent = Credentials.getClient(this).getHintPickerIntent(hintRequest)
```

```
// Java
PendingIntent intent = Credentials.getClient(this).getHintPickerIntent(hintRequest);
```

`Credentials` is found in this package: `com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.Credentials`.

---

Full working example which calls `buttonClicked` when a button is pressed:

```
// Kotlin

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.Credential
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.Credentials
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.CredentialsApi
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.HintRequest

class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // ... onCreate Functions, etc

    // Arbitrary number to identify the request for crednetials
    private val iRequestCodePhoneNumber = 100

    // Button click listener
    fun buttonClicked(@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER") view: View) {
        val hintRequest = HintRequest.Builder()
            .setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)
            .build()

        val intent = Credentials.getClient(this).getHintPickerIntent(hintRequest)

        startIntentSenderForResult(
            intent.intentSender,
            iRequestCodePhoneNumber, null, 0, 0, 0
        )
    }

    // Parse the result of the HintPicker (i.e., get the selected phone number)
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        // resultCode:
        //   Activity.RESULT_OK (-1) = number selected
        //   Activity.RESULT_CANCELED (0) = user touched outside the HintPicker (do nothing)
        //   CredentialsApi.ACTIVITY_RESULT_OTHER_ACCOUNT (1001) = "None of the above" (do nothing; treat as same use case as 'Cancelling')
        //   CredentialsApi.ACTIVITY_RESULT_NO_HINTS_AVAILABLE (1002) = no numbers found, probably no SIM card
        if (requestCode == iRequestCodePhoneNumber && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val credential: Credential? = data?.getParcelableExtra(Credential.EXTRA_KEY)
            val phoneNumber = credential?.id

            // *** Do something with the phone number here ***

        } else if (
            requestCode == iRequestCodePhoneNumber &&
            resultCode == CredentialsApi.ACTIVITY_RESULT_NO_HINTS_AVAILABLE
        ) {
            // *** No phone numbers available ***
            Toast.makeText(this, "No phone numbers found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

This will generate a popup like this:

[image: User selecting phone number available on their device]

#### UPDATED :

###### **The upper code is also deprecated as of now**

###### Step 1 :

Getting `GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest`

```
val request: GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest = GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest.builder().build()

        Identity.getSignInClient(requireActivity())
            .getPhoneNumberHintIntent(request)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                phoneNumberHintIntentResultLauncher.launch(
                    IntentSenderRequest.Builder(it.intentSender).build()
                )
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d(TAG, it.message)
            }
```

###### Step 2 :

Setting up `ActivityResultLauncher` IntentSenderRequest

```
private val phoneNumberHintIntentResultLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest> = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()
    ) { result ->
        try {
            val phoneNumber = Identity.getSignInClient(requireActivity()).getPhoneNumberFromIntent(result.data)
            //Do more stuff with phoneNumber
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, it.message)
        }
    }
```

Image Description : [image: Mobile Number]

For official google documentation : [Click Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/phone-number-hint/android)

Comment: I sympathise with anyone stumbling on this answer, as the documentation for migrating away from the deprecated `GoogleApiClient`s is quite poor (no mappings provided for old/new classes or techniques). Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thank you, Christopher! It works well. I totally agree with you regarding the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, wish I could do more up votes.

Comment: Can anyone tell what should we pass in Function `buttonClicked(View view)` the view place, if I use it in java

Comment: You should not be calling `buttonClicked(View view)` directly. In an XML layout files, select a Button (which is a subclass of `View`) and set it's onclick event listener to "buttonClicked". If you're doing it right, Android Studio should auto-suggest available methods.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it was very annoying to see deprecated calls everywhere in my code. How consistent did this api work for you? I have 2 Samsung phones with SIM cards with different api levels (24 and 28) but it gives 1002 as a result code and content of intent differs in both of them. Is this reliable and am I doing something wrong or should I switch to something else? More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66252392/android-hintpicker-results-in-1002-while-retrieving-phone-number

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Best of luck finding an answer.

Comment: For some reason, on a real device, the new code gives me `ApiException: 16: No phone number is found on this device` , while the old one works fine. And, on emulator, it's the opposite (old doesn't work, and new works fine). How come? I've reported this here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/266967506

Comment: I've found that the new API works only if in your phone settings, in the section about the phone -> sim card is set phone number. But this looks like depends on operator's sim card, because some sim cards provide that phone number some do not. Also, some phones allow input phone numbre manually, for example, Xiomi, but pixel doesn't allow to do that.

Answer (score 4):

Use this function **requestHint()** when you want to request for phone number hint.

```
       GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest request = GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest.builder().build();
    Identity.getSignInClient(this)
            .getPhoneNumberHintIntent(request)
            .addOnSuccessListener(result -> {
                try {
                    IntentSender intentSender = result.getIntentSender();
                    hintResult.launch(new IntentSenderRequest.Builder(intentSender).build());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("Error launching", "error occurred in launching Activity result");
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.i("Failure occurred", "Failure getting phone number"));
```

Here, we use this to handle the result (previously, we used onActivityResult() for this).

```
    ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest> hintResult = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(),
        result -> {
            if(result!=null){
                try {
                    String phoneNum = Identity.getSignInClient(getApplicationContext()).getPhoneNumberFromIntent(result.getData());
                    // Do your work with phone number here
                } catch (ApiException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: after applying your code there nothing depreciate code in my class thank you

Comment: HintRequest is deprecated, and so does Credentials.